# Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed by remote host during rsync backup

Tags: bash

I have 2 web servers. Let's call them local and remote just for simplicity.
Local: I've only ftp and cron access, Remote: ssh/ftp

I wrote a simple backup script, which tars the files and then sends them to the remote server. (called in cron)
Local server is added in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote server to make connection without using password.

```
cd $FILES_TO_BACKUP_DIR
for dir in */
do
    base=$(basename "$dir")
    tar -czpf "$BACKUP_DIR/${base}-$DATE.tar.gz" "$dir"
    rsync -az -e "ssh -p $REMOTE_HOST_PORT -i $KEY_PATH" $BACKUP_DIR $REMOTE_HOST_ADDRESS:$REMOTE_BACKUP_DIR
    rm $BACKUP_DIR/${base}-$DATE.tar.gz
done
```

I think it works fine - the files are appearing on the remote server.

However I'm not sure about this message:
`Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed by remote host.`
It appears different number of times each time the script is called.

For the testing purposes, I copy around 20 tars. I've added echos with timestamps to check in which point it is happening and it's only after creating tar. Sometimes even on the first loop run when the connection shouldn't be established yet.

I don't think it breaks anything, but I'm curious why this is happening and if it's possible, how can I prevent such behavior. (I've tried using `rsync -q` to suppress the message, but it does not work.)

How it looks with set -x:

```
./backup.sh
+ cd /home/tobackup/
+ for dir in '*/'
++ basename lgsm/
+ base=lgsm
+ tar -czpf /home/test/_backups/backups-tmp/lgsm-09-01-2020.tar.gz lgsm/
+ rsync -vaz -e 'ssh -p PORT' /home/test/_backups/backups-tmp USER@IP:/home/backups_test/_backups/backups
sending incremental file list
backups-tmp/
backups-tmp/lgsm-09-01-2020.tar.gz
backups-tmp/serverfiles-09-01-2020.tar.gz
Connection to IP closed by remote host.

sent 237,480,856 bytes  received 10,786 bytes  6,168,614.08 bytes/sec
total size is 241,069,740  speedup is 1.02
+ rm /home/test/_backups/backups-tmp/lgsm-09-01-2020.tar.gz
+ for dir in '*/'
++ basename log/
+ base=log
+ tar -czpf /home/test/_backups/backups-tmp/log-09-01-2020.tar.gz log/
+ rsync -vaz -e 'ssh -p PORT' /home/test/_backups/backups-tmp USER@IP:/home/backups_test/_backups/backups
sending incremental file list
backups-tmp/
backups-tmp/log-09-01-2020.tar.gz
Connection to IP closed by remote host.

sent 900 bytes  received 81 bytes  654.00 bytes/sec
total size is 237,899,887  speedup is 242,507.53
+ rm /home/test/_backups/backups-tmp/log-09-01-2020.tar.gz
+ for dir in '*/'
++ basename serverfiles/
+ base=serverfiles
+ tar -czpf /home/test/_backups/backups-tmp/serverfiles-09-01-2020.tar.gz serverfiles/
```

Comment: The error is coming from the `ssh` command, since that's the only thing that creates network connections. It might be some kind of network error or timeout, and `rsync` automatically reconnects.

Comment: @Barmar If the connection is restored automatically, is it possible to suppress this kind of messages? I want to see only meaningful errors, because there is a tool given by the host that allows to send e-mail whenever there is any log and I'd like to use it. (But not every single run, with not important logs) I've tried using -q parameter in rsync, but it still shows the message.

Comment: I've been using `scp` for many years, and I don't think I've ever seen this message, so I'm not really sure why it's happening. And that was just a guess that it's automatically restarting.

Comment: You can try the `--quiet` option.

Comment: In fact, there are questions on [unix.se] and other sites asking how to make `rsync` restart after a network error, so now I don't think it's doing that by itself. Are you sure the files are being transferred completely when this happens?

Comment: I'm quite sure that files are identical. (I've check sizes of all files and checksum of some of them)

Comment: As I've checked it further, the message always appears between `tar` and `rsync` commands

Comment: That makes no sense. You confirmed this with `set -x`?

Comment: I've used `certutil -hashfile FILENAME md5` for both files on win machine. I'm not sure what do you mean by `set -x`?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, it will show each line as it's executing. Then you can see precisely where the error is happening. I don't understand how the error could happen between tar and rsync, it has to come from rsync.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot do that. I don't have ssh access on the "local" server. (only crontab) I'll try to do it from the different server with normal ssh.

Comment: @Barmar updated the question with the details from `set -x`. Also tried --quiet, it still shows Connection closed messages - I guess the msg type is error.

Comment: The message is definitely coming from `rsync`, but I'm not sure why. [unix.se] would be a better place to ask, as this has nothing to do with your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've compared described behavior between 5 different servers and only the connection with one particular server has this issue.

After checking with md5 checksum I'm sure that files are identical.

As the warning does not affect anything I've decided to suppress the message.
For now, I've modified the backup script on the server so in case of any use of ssh, it logs output to the file first by:  `>> $BACKUP_LOGS_FILE 2>&1` at the end of the command.

At the very end of the script I'm using grep to filter out the output: `grep -v 'Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed by remote host.' $BACKUP_LOGS_FILE`

However, if anyone has any explanation what can be causing this, feel free to add your answer.